# Different threads see different order of execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

This is the code from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>

std::atomic<bool> x = {false};
std::atomic<bool> y = {false};
std::atomic<int> z = {0};

void write_x()
{
    x.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}

void write_y()
{
    y.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}

void read_x_then_y()
{
    while (!x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
        ;
    if (y.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) {
        ++z;
    }
}

void read_y_then_x()
{
    while (!y.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
        ;
    if (x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) {
        ++z;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread a(write_x);
    std::thread b(write_y);
    std::thread c(read_x_then_y);
    std::thread d(read_y_then_x);
    a.join(); b.join(); c.join(); d.join();
    assert(z.load() != 0);  // will never happen
}
```

Now, if we consider that the memory accesses caused by thread a and b are executed with a different memory order argument (like std::memory_order_relaxed) and the accesses caused by c and d remain the same, how it is possible for the threads c and d to see a different order of the stores inside x and y? (or should all memory accesses allowed to be std::memory_order_relaxed?)

What causes two different reader threads to see a different order of execution? 
What architectures allow this? 
Is it because cache updates are not made in the same order?

Comment: with multithreading you don t know the order of execution so the thread c could be are executed before the a and b and the d could be are executed after so the couldn t be same same for c and d as you saw.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with the order of the threads, but with the order in which threads c and d see memory changes.

Comment: Herb Sutter has a [very good lecture](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2) where he explains how the prefetcher and the write-back buffers that a processor core uses to avoid stalling on memory accesses can be modeled as an execution order problem.

Comment: If I consider a situation where thread a writes to its own cache before thread b writes to its own cache (in a real chronological order), it is correct if I assume that x is updated first in the cache of thread c and y is updated first in the cache of thread d (because of the way the data is propagated through caches) ? Are there architectures that allow that?

Comment: A store does not have to be committed to RAM to be seen by another CPU, on AMD for example.

Comment: I did not assume anywhere that the writes were sent to RAM, just passed between processors' caches.

Comment: I found this [link](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/WRL-95-7.pdf). Section 5.2.3 might answer my question. So is my assumption valid?

Comment: To be able to snoop each other, they have all have to sit on the same cache bus (making assumptions about the arch). It can easily be that c can snoop a, but not b, and d can snoop b, but not a.

Comment: @Cubbi So the architecture you described allows for a different order to be seen by different threads (better said independent processors). Thank you.

Comment: @Cubbi I still have some issues imagining such an architecture. Considering that A modifies X, then B modifies Y (chronologically), wouldn't these modifications invalidate all the corresponding cache blocks in all the processors, which would cause them to get a read miss and to wait for the correct value to be loaded? Cause if that is the case, if thread C sees that X was modified first then in thread D, after reading Y, X would be invalidated, and the correct value would be loaded after a read miss. Or does such an architecture have a different way of signalling a write from a processor?

Comment: Invalidation doesn't have to be acted upon unless there was a barrier

Comment: @Cubbi Ok. Thank you.